# Split Records Equally Into Groups

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm wanting to build a schedule program(I want to write the sql to do it then I will build  a php site to execute it). For starters I would like to split up the students I have at my school between the teachers. I need them to be gender balanced, meaning equal or within say no more than 30% of one gender over the other in each class.

So I have a students Table with all grade levels 1-5 and a teachers table with a field that designates what grade they teach. I then have a courses table that has the course that each teacher teaches, it contains a field that has the class size limit (only 18 students allowed etc) as well as the teacher ID who is teaching the course.

```
Student Table Example:

Student_ID  Grade_Level
253486           1
365896           2
485785           3
968654           4
154278           5



Teacher Table Example:

Teacher_ID  Grade Taught
253              1
584              2
985              3
647              4
254              5

Course Table Example:

Course_ID   Class_Limit Teacher_ID
5007010      15            253
5007011      15            584
5007012      18            985
5007013      18            647
5007014      10            254
```

**What I would like to be the end result is have the records dump into a table that has three fields, The teacher id, the course id and the student id.**

Once I get this figured out, I would like to eventually build on it and add more ways to divide them up.

Incase you're wondering why I want to do this is because our current scheduler dosen't support this kind of scheduling, and I'm not sure when, if ever they will add it. But even just this simple step would save tons of time currently.

I appreciate any input or help.

Comment: `I need them to be gender balanced` .. but there is no gender information in your setup ..?

Comment: Gender balancing is sexism! If only I & other guy sign up, with the rest of the female persuasion, we are _forced_ to be in different classes purely based on our genitals! I object :P

Comment: Sorry forgot to add there is a field for students that is either M or F

Comment: All kidding aside, this is a _lot_ easier handled in application logic then in barebones sql...

Comment: That's what I was kinda thinking but I'm better with sql than php so I was hoping there might be something in sql I wasn't thinking of.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the approach that you can take.

The key idea is to count the number of male and female students in each class and then to assign them.  The assignment is pretty easy, if we have the information.  So, assume we have it:

```
with magictable (
      <subquery here is nummale and numfemale in each class
     ),
     classinfo (
      select mt.*,
             sum(nummales) over (partition by grade) - 1 as endrange_male,
             sum(nummales) over (partition by grade) - nummales as startrange_male,
             sum(numfemales) over (partition by grade) - 1 as endrange_female,
             sum(numfemales) over (partition by grade) - numfemales as startrange_female
      from magictable mt
     )
select
from (select s.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by grade, gender order by student_id) as seqnum
      from student s
     ) s join
     classinfo ci
     on (s.gender = 'M' and s.seqnum between startrange_male and endrange_male) or
        (s.gender = 'F' and s.seqnum between startrange_female and endrange_female)
```

So, this turns the assignment information into the calculation of how many males and females in each class.  You may have other ways to accomplish this, so I will give an approximate answer here.

You can count the number of students in each grade, the number of males, and the number of females.  Calculate the number of "excess" students, by subtracting the actual number of students from the total capacity.  This gives the actual size of each class.  Then partition this by the male/female ratio.

The following query shows how to do this:

```
  select c.*,
         (c.class_limit - ((csum.maxcapacity - ssum.numstudents)/csum.numcourses)) as actsize,
         (c.class_limit - ((csum.maxcapacity - ssum.numstudents)/csum.numcourses)) * (NumMales / NumStudents) as actMales,
         (c.class_limit - ((csum.maxcapacity - ssum.numstudents)/csum.numcourses)) * (NumFemales / NumStudents) as actFemales
  from course c join
       teacher t
       on c.teacher_id = t.teacher_id
       (select grade, count(*) as numcourses, SUM(class_limit) as maxcapacity
        from course c join
             teacher t
             on c.teacher_id = t.teacher_id
        group by grade
       ) csum
       on t.grade = csum.grade join
       (select grade, sum(case when gender = 'M' then 1 else 0 end) as NumMales,
               sum(case when gender = 'F' then 1 else 0 end) as NumFemales,
               count(*) as NumStudents
        from s
        group by grade
       ) ssum
       on t.grade = ssum.grade;
```

The problem is, this is an approximation because it deals in fractional students.  And, alas, real students come only in non-fractional sizes.

There is a real solution to this to calculate discrete sizes.  Instead, though, I would just round NumMales and NumFemales up to the next integer and use that for the estimate.  This is probably good enough for your purposes.

And, the code in this solution is to illustration the solution.  It may have syntactic problems.

Answer (score 0):

Following normalization principles and using your existing schema, <strike>I'm guessing that what you asked for is not really what you want</strike> .

I don't understand why you would need a teacherID in the table because you already have a courses table with a TeacherID FK.

I think what you need is a `StudentCourses` table. This table would have two fields, studentID and courseID (courseID being the FK to Course table and studentID to Student table. With a two part composite PK of Student ID and CourseID.

Sample data would look like

```
      StudentRegistrations

    CourseID            StudentID
   5007010                26352
   5007010                26732
   6003790                26352
```

This is unless I completely misunderstood and you are just asking us to write a SP to randomly put the students in courses. Still, my points I made above still stand.

Comment: You make good points. That would work just having the course I'd and student id. I'm decently proficient in sql, but far from a sql master. But I am wanting to use a stored procedure to randomly asking students to classes, while maintaining gender balance within the courses. I'm just not sure how to go about it.

Comment: @AcidBurn85 Gotcha, That's a pretty steep request for SO without starting it yourself, but it looks like Gordon tried to tackle it with his answer -- give that a shot.